# Log4Net FileAppender not thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, log4net, thread-safety, fileappender

I need to log to a file because the customer doesn't have a console of something where I can log to with log4net.
Now I read that the FileAppender is not thread safe. Is there anyhow a way to log to file within an app that logs out of different threads or what would be a common alternative?

Answer (score 16):

Log4Net itself [is thread-safe](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#thread-safe) even if `FileAppender` isn't - the framework manages everything for you. So long as you log in the normal way (rather than directly writing to the appender) you should be fine.